# How can I set an EditText to have italic hint text?

Tags: android-widget

How can I set the hint text of an EditText to be italic in Android?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14684559/

Answer (score 1):

```
EditText.setText("");
EditText.setHint("hint");
EditText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.ITALIC);
....
EditText.setText("text");
EditText.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.NORMAL);
```

Answer (score 0):

To set text as italic, you can do the following:

```
EditText.setText(Html.fromHtml("<small><i>" + "Text Hint Here" + "</i></small>"));
```

If you would like the italic text to be a hint - when the EditText is empty for example - you must implement a method to check the text length, and when it is equal to zero, apply the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in XML.

First declare your hint in the "strings.xml" file. Your define it to be italic by using the "< i >" tag

```
<string name="EditBoxHint"><i>Whatever you want to show</i></string>
```

Finally, in the layout declaration you add your hint referencing this previously declared string.

```
<EditText
    ...
    android:hint="@string/EditBoxHint"
    ...
/>
```