# Set Edittexts hint text style as italic

Tags: android, android-edittext, italic

I need to set the hint of a EditText as italic style, but I can't find any place how to do it.

Some one here has a clue how to do it or do I have to accept that is impossible?

Comment: Was a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3465576/

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Inside strings.xml

```
 <string name="hint1"><i>Your hint here</i></string>
```

In your .xml file

```
  <EditText android:hint="@string/hint1" />
```

Comment: Thank you. Quite easy. Didn't know that I could use tags inside a tag.

Comment: For the record, I just tried `<em></em>` and it did not work.

Comment: @LiterateCorvette - what is em?

Comment: @Deepzz emphasis instead of italics, generally the same as `<i>` to the user, but it is now the preferred tag in most use cases. [Here's an explanation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/em).

Answer (score 21):

Add one string value in Strings.xml as `<i>your hint here</i>` and try to set it in your EditText in the xml

Solution 2:

```
if(youredittext.getText().toString().length()==0)
{
    youredittext.setTypeface(null,Typeface.ITALIC);
}
else
{
youredittext.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
}
```

Comment: Your first solution with setting `<i>hint</i>`works very well and look good in the xml.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml, you can set a TextStyle. This TextStyle is applicable on your text and your hint.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/editText"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="@Your text here"
android:textStyle="italic"/>
```

Comment: TextStyle impacts the entered text, OP wants to set the style of hint text only.